# Jetty embedded -- error to load in SelectChannelConnector and setPort

Tags: jetty, embedded-jetty

I want to integrate jetty as module to be used as server for my application.

I m using maven to load dependencies for jetty as follow :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-all</artifactId>
    <version>9.3.7.v20160115</version>
</dependency>
```

And I'm following this tutorial to buil my server https://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Tutorial/Embedding_Jetty#Configuring_Connectors

here is the code I want to run :

```
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Handler;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.DefaultHandler;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerList;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ResourceHandler;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector;

public class FileServer {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Server server = new Server();
        SelectChannelConnector connector = new SelectChannelConnector();
        connector.setPort(8080);
        server.addConnector(connector);


ResourceHandler resource_handler = new ResourceHandler();
resource_handler.setDirectoriesListed(true);
resource_handler.setWelcomeFiles(new String[]{"index.html"});

resource_handler.setResourceBase(".");

HandlerList handlers = new HandlerList();
handlers.setHandlers(new Handler[]{resource_handler, new DefaultHandler()});
server.setHandler(handlers);

server.start();
server.join();

    }
}
```

However i've got errors in this part :

```
SelectChannelConnector connector = new SelectChannelConnector();
connector.setPort(8080);
server.addConnector(connector);
```

it cannot detect SelectChannelConnector neither setPort() !

Any help ? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The giant red box at the start of that wiki page tells you ...

> Jetty 7 and Jetty 8 are now EOL (End of Life)
>
> All development and stable releases are being performed with Jetty 9.
>
> This wiki is now officially out of date and all content has been moved to the [Jetty Documentation Hub](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation)
>
> Direct Link to updated documentation: http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/embedding-jetty.html

In short, you can't use Jetty 8 code and mechanisms on Jetty 9.

Follow the link to the Jetty 9 documentation to see the up to date documentation and code examples

Comment: Thank you very much @Joakim... I havent make attention to that precious comment :)